# Condition check before action

Tags: android

I have three input text boxes on a page and a submit button on a page on android. How do I add a condition that, only if all three inputs are given only then the submit button should perform its action?

Comment: everytime the button is pressed first check if the textedit have a desired value, if condition is true then proceed with your specific action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might pay to create a custom OnClickListener that takes all three textfields as view references. Then, within your onClick method, you could conditionally check that the value of all three check boxes is not null or empty. Is that what you're looking for?

```
public class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{

TextView text1;
TextView text2;
TextView text3;

public MyOnClickListener(int index, TextView text1, TextView text2, TextView text3)
{
    this.index = index;
    this.text1 = text1;
    this.text2 = text2;
    this.text3 = text3;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    //check values conditionally here
}
```